# Selecting artifacts on basis of value in selectbox using SOAP interface

Tags: rest, soap, tuleap

Using Tuleap 8.13.99.65 on Centos 6.7

Using the get_artifacts.php example script I tried to modify it to find all artifacts in a tracker with a status of 'Completed' however when I run the script it returns all records regardless of their status.  The status field is called status_id and is a fixed select box. I've found the bind_status_id for the Completed status and included it but I still get all artifacts returned.

I'm pretty new to this so it is almost definitely being caused by a mistake on my part but I can't spot it.

I've included a small section of the code, where the query is defined, can anyone spot where I've gone wrong?

```
$project_id = 0; //not needed
$tracker_id = 20;
$offset     = 0;
$limit      = 100; 
$criteria = array(
    array(
        'field_name' => 'status_id',
        'value' => array(
            'bind_value' => array(
                'bind_value_id' =>  '504',
                'bind_value_label' => 'Completed'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I've just learned that the SOAP interface is deprecated and will be discontinued soon so I guess my question is no longer relevant.

Time to learn the REST API instead!